# Best way to filter system logs using Datadog + GKE?

Tags: kubernetes

I've recently set up datadog agent on a K8s cluster in GKE. The cluster is ran using GKE autopilot. Logs are being collected from my services, but they are also being collected from internal services such as netd, gke-metrics-agent, celium, prometheus, etc. (I'm unsure which of these are related to K8s itself, GKE, or Autopilot).

I'd like to only collect logs from my deployed services so the others don't clog up our log feed or set off any alerts. Is there a good pattern for doing this? Currently I'm adding them all to `containerExclude`, but I'd prefer not to do this as there are many services so it's easy to miss them in the config and allow unwanted logs in.

Here's my current datadog-values.yaml I'm using to deploy via Helm:

```
datadog:
  apiKey: api-ey
  appKey: app-key
  clusterName: my-cluster
  containerExclude: "image:image-package-extractor image:gcp-filestore-csi-driver image:gke-metrics-agent image:gke-metadata-server image:agent image:cilium image:metrics-server image:cluster-proportional-autoscaler image:netd image:fluent-bit image:fluent-bit-gke-exporter image:gcp-compute-persistent-disk-csi-driver image:k8s-dns-node-cache"
  kubeStateMetricsCore:
    enabled: true
  kubeStateMetricsEnabled: false
  logs:
    enabled: true
    containerCollectAll: true
agents:
  containers:
    agent:
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 200m
          memory: 256Mi
    traceAgent:
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 100m
          memory: 200Mi
    processAgent:
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 100m
          memory: 200Mi
    clusterAgent:
      replicas: 2
      createPodDisruptionBudget: true
  priorityClassCreate: true
providers:
  gke:
    autopilot: true
```